# Errors using arcpy.CalculateField_management

Tags: arcpy, excel, error-000728

EDIT: What I forgot to mention when I first had this question is that I was trying to do these calculations on a layer which had joins, BUT where the join was on data that was added from an Excel file.  ArcGIS does not seem to like data from Excel files.

I am trying to use the [arcpy.CalculateField_management](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000004m000000) function and running into some trouble.

I have a shapefile called district_plans, and to this shapefile I have joined a table of data (the table of data is named kdp).  I want to change a field in district_plans to the data in one of the columns of kdp.

Trying the following

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management("district_plans","district_plans.drawplan", "!kdp$.plan_4!","PYTHON")
```

yields the following error message

```
Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<string>", line 1, in
<module>   File "c:\program files x86)\arcgis\desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\management.py",
line 3183, in CalculateField     raise e ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters 
are not valid. ERROR 000728: Field district_plans.drawplan does not exist within 
table Failed to execute (CalculateField).
```

Trying the following

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management("district_plans","drawplan", "!kdp$.plan_4!","PYTHON")
```

yields the following error message

```
Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<string>", line 1, in 
<module>   File "c:\program files x86)\arcgis\desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", 
line 3183, in CalculateField     raise e ExecuteError: ERROR 999999: Error executing 
function. Failed to execute (CalculateField).
```

The following variations all yield errors:

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management("district_plans","district_plans.drawplan", "!plan_4!","PYTHON")

arcpy.CalculateField_management("district_plans","drawplan", "!plan_4!","PYTHON")
```

I am able to manually perform the field calculation using the field calculator on the drawplan column in the attribute table of district_plans, so I am not sure why the Python version does not work.

Comment: do you get an error with replacing "PYTHON" argument with "PYTHON_9.3" ?

Comment: @mwil Yes, same type of errors even if I replace "PYTHON" with "PYTHON_9.3".

Comment: are you using this in python window? or as an standalone script? And try this:     

arcpy.CalculateField_management("district_plans","district_plans.drawplan", "!kdp$.plan_4!","PYTHON_9.3","#")

Comment: does your join table name contains $ sign? In your question you have said, "the table of data is named kdp"

Comment: @FaridCher I tried what you suggested and it did not work either.  The kdp data table is read in from an excel file and is named kdp.  However, when I manually perform the field calculation using the field calculator the field shows up as kdp$.plan_4 .

Comment: Try to first export your excel sheet to dbf or geodatabase table and then create your map join, and then calculate. I'm pretty sure the problem is from the excel data source!

Comment: So it is definitely something to do with the join.  As soon as I remove the join the code arcpy.CalculateField_management("district_plans","drawplan","!polyID!","PYTHON") works just fine (where polyID is a field belonging to district_plans and not part of a join).  Any tips on how to convert my Excel spreadsheet into a dbf?

Comment: Table to Table http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001200000027000000 will import. It seems the errors occur with Excel files *as they are being used* and not just on read. This tool will import the Excel to a more stable format... normally though I create a personal GDB, open with Microsoft Access and import that way - just be careful of $ and spaces in field names - Access has no problems with them but Esri does. The error message is about the 'to' field, perhaps it should be "[district_plans.drawplan]" as the calculate to field...

Comment: The layer is district_plans but what is the feature class name? Can we see the code where the join is performed?

Comment: I am not sure if I am using the correct terminology.  I have a shape file named district_plans that is a grid composed of squares, where the field polyID uniquely identifies each square.  drawplan is another field I created in the attribute table of the district_plans shape file (which I think is what you are calling a feature class?).

Comment: I have tried using Table to Table.  I first added my excel sheet to the TOC (right click Layers, Add Data..., select Excel sheet).  I then brought up the Table to Table tool via search.  For Input Rows I chose the spreadsheet, for Output Rows I put in my desktop path, and for Output Name I used 'kdp_dbtable.dbf' but that threw errors.

Comment: Rather than a back and forth discussion in comments I think you would be better to **edit** your question so that it contains a single usage and corresponding error, and then to keep it in sync with requests for clarifications that are sought via comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that the data joined to the district_plans layer came from an Excel file as pointed out by @Farid Cher and @Michael Miles-Stimson.  Although I was not able to get the [Table to Table](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001200000027000000) function to work, I found the following code (located in this [GitHub repo](https://github.com/GeoDaSandbox/sandbox/blob/master/pyGDsandbox/dataIO.py)) which takes a [Pandas dataframe](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) and writes it out as a .dbf.

```
import pysal as ps
import numpy as np

def df2dbf(df, dbf_path, my_specs=None):
    '''
    Convert a pandas.DataFrame into a dbf.
    __author__  = "Dani Arribas-Bel <darribas@asu.edu> "
    ...
    Arguments
    ---------
    df          : DataFrame
                  Pandas dataframe object to be entirely written out to a dbf
    dbf_path    : str
                  Path to the output dbf. It is also returned by the function
    my_specs    : list
                  List with the field_specs to use for each column.
                  Defaults to None and applies the following scheme:
                    * int: ('N', 14, 0)
                    * float: ('N', 14, 14)
                    * str: ('C', 14, 0)
    '''
    if my_specs:
        specs = my_specs
    else:
        type2spec = {int: ('N', 20, 0),
                     np.int64: ('N', 20, 0),
                     float: ('N', 36, 15),
                     np.float64: ('N', 36, 15),
                     str: ('C', 14, 0)
        }
        types = [type(df[i].iloc[0]) for i in df.columns]
        specs = [type2spec[t] for t in types]
    db = ps.open(dbf_path, 'w')
    db.header = list(df.columns)
    db.field_spec = specs
    for i, row in df.T.iteritems():
        db.write(row)
    db.close()

    return dbf_path
```

After joining the data contained in the .dbf file everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to the [Table to Table](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001200000027000000) tool, you could try using the [Excel to Table](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001200000055000000) tool. From my experience the [Table to Table](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001200000027000000) tool does not always convert the Microsoft Excel sheets properly, while the [Excel to Table](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001200000055000000) tool always did the job fine.

Edit: I just realized that this tool is only available for ArcGIS Desktop 10.2 and onwards.